# Atribuir valores às views de um AlertDialog

Tags: android, textview, alertdialog

Criei um layout personalizado para o meu AlertDialog com um TextView nele, e uma imagem, mas não consigo colocar valores nele. Alguém sabe como resolver?

Segue o código:

```
private void carregaAlert(){
    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alerta, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ClassificacaoActivity.this);

    dialog.setView(v).setPositiveButton("SIM", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            Intent vai = new Intent(ClassificacaoActivity.this, InteraActivity.class);
            startActivity(vai);
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("NÃO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            // Continua na tela
        }
    });
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ima);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.trofeu);
    dialog.show();
}
```

```
10-13 21:50:52.280 844-844/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
10-13 21:50:52.280 844-844/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
10-13 21:50:52.482 844-844/br.com.franciscocartaxo.aps2 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/br.com.franciscocartaxo.aps2-1/lib/x86
10-13 21:50:52.502 844-844/br.com.franciscocartaxo.aps2 I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
10-13 21:50:52.644 844-844/br.com.franciscocartaxo.aps2 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
10-13 21:50:52.884 844-874/br.com.franciscocartaxo.aps2 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-13 21:50:52.885 844-874/br.com.franciscocartaxo.aps2 D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
10-13 21:50:52.893 844-874/br.com.franciscocartaxo.aps2 D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa2817a60: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
10-13 21:50:52.912 844-874/br.com.franciscocartaxo.aps2 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa2817a60: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa2854330)
10-13 21:50:52.938 844-874/br.com.franciscocartaxo.aps2 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa2817a60: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa2854330)
10-13 21:50:56.047 844-844/br.com.franciscocartaxo.aps2 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
10-13 21:50:56.056 844-874/br.com.franciscocartaxo.aps2 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa2817a60: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa2854330)
```

Comment: O que exatamente tá acontecendo? O que era esperado? Você colocou um log mas não tem nada relacionado ao seu problema nele.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obter as referências às views do layout do AlertDialog você tem de usar o método `findViewById()` desse layout e não o da Activity.

Em vez de

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ima);
```

use

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ima);
```

Comment: Valeeu, Ramaral! Era isso mesmo!

Answer (score 0):

Francisco, nessas horas eu normalmente crio DialogFragment, que seguem os principios de fragments comuns, recebendo layout.xml e tudo mais e a forma de implantação é bem simples, por exemplo, para fazer a chamada de um FragmentDialog na sua função carregarAlert():

```
DialogoFragmento fragmentCardapio = new DialogoFragmento ();
            fragmentCardapio.show(MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager(), "Chamar Dialog fRAGMENT");
```

Com isso ele chamará o fragment que você criou que extende a classe DialogFragment:

```
public class EventoDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener{

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_evento, container, false);
    this.getDialog().setTitle("Dialog chamado pela Main");
   //Daqui para frente você pode inserir o código como se estivesse trabalhando com um fragment normal

    return view;
}
}
```

Você  verá que o arquivo XML se preocupara em construir o objeto do tamanho exato do layout, assim você poderá acertar as coisas!
Espero ter ajudado!